# Regex command for split and match

Tags: regex

I'd like to check if all substrings splitted by some delimeter are matching pattern.
This is my pattern `[S][0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1,2}` But it is pattern for one element. Sometimes someone will put `S1234567A, S0X00000B` in input box and I'd like to check if all elements match the pattern. In this case my regex will say it's OK only because he found matching string.
I've got no access to the source code so that I could split it and check every element.
Is there a way to do this in regex?

Comment: Note that `S0X00000B` does not actually match your pattern, I believe you wanted to say `S0000000B`

Comment: I wanted `S0X00000B` cause it should fail, yet my regex said it is fine, because the other one is fine :P

Comment: Ah, then OK, I just wanted to provide a regex fiddle showing how the updated regex *matches* *correct* input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an additional `*`-quantified group anchoring the whole expression at start and end of string with `^` and `$`:

```
^S[0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1,2}(?:,\s*S[0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1,2})*$
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTDQU0/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `S[0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1,2}` - `S`, 7 digits, two or one uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?:` - start of the `*` quantified group:

  - `,` - a comma (if there can be whitespace before the comma, add `\s*` before)
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
  - `S[0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1,2}` - see above
- `)*` - the end of the group, `*` quantifier makes it match zero or more occurrences
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :)